# How to modify this method to return an array with key => values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the method that is working, it parses all HTML table rows, and insert them in an array, so it turns into an array of rows, but only with row values, no keys:

```
function tableToJson(table){
    var AoA = $(table+' > tbody > tr').map(function(){
        return [
            $('td',this).map(function(){
                return $(this).text();
            }).get()
        ];
    }).get();
    return JSON.stringify(AoA);
}
```

Output:

```
[
['x','1'],
['y','2'],
['z','3']
]
```

What could I change to make it return an array of dictionaries (with keys and values)?
Like:

```
[
{'address': 'x','number': '1'},
{'address': 'y','number': '2'},
{'address': 'z','number': '3'}
]
```

I've tried to replace the line:
`return $(this).text();`
 For:
`return $(this).attr('name') => $(this).text();`
 But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
function tableToJson(table){
  var r = [];
  $(table+' > tbody > tr').each(function(){
    var e = $(this);
    r.push({address:e.attr('name'), number:e.text()});
  });
  return r;
}
```

Of course, the above creates an Array of Objects. You can see their name and values like:

```
var tblRws = tableToJson('#tableId');
$.each(tblRws, function(i, v){
  console.log('Row:'+i+'; Address:'+v.address+'; Number:'+v.number+';');
});
```

I'm not sure why you wanted to `JSON.strigify()` the results. If it's for AJAX, you can just use an Object as the `data` argument. Also, you might want to set your `dataType` for the type of `data` you would like back from the Server.

Comment: it's for ajax, I'm trying to parse the info from a table to post it to PHP, I don't know if it's a good approach, but was the best that I've thought, how can I set it on datatype?

Comment: If you're using `$.ajax({url:'url.php', data:tableToJson('#tableId'), dataType:'JSON', complete:function(results){ /* do stuff with results here */ }})` or after your `function` argument, as in `$.post('url.php', tabelToJson('#tableId'), function(results){ /* executes upon completion */ }, 'JSON')`. Change to `$.get()` if using `$_GET` PHP Server Side.

Comment: no way to post it in php format key => value, by JSON, right?

Comment: You send JSON, or a serialized String to the Server, as your `data` argument. When the response is sent PHP handles it, then passes the response into your `complete` function's argument. Of course that function is executed Asynchronously, when the `XMLHttpRequestObject.status === 200 && XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState === 4`. If you want to read a JSON response, after PHP has executed, you need to `echo json_encode($assoc_array_here)`. I don't get your question. Hope that helps.

Comment: I would like to post an array of arrays with ajax to PHP, but with associative arrays, so I wouldn't have to format the ajax post data to the format key => value in php. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Use `$assocArray = json_decode($_POST['JSON_property']);` to get an Associative Array in PHP. `JSON_property` is like `{JSON_property: 'JSON value here'}`, which is `data` property or argument depending on AJAX used. For all `$assocArray = json_decode($_POST);`. I recommend that you use a specific `$_POST['JSON_property']`, and also do checks Sever Side like you would if you weren't using AJAX, like an HTML/PHP only form.

Comment: I recommend not sending Arrays to the Server since `JSON.stringify()` is not backward compatible.

Comment: `$.post('url.php' {specific:JSON.stringify(tabelToJson('#tableId'))}, function(results){ /* executes upon completion */ }, 'JSON')`. `specific` is a property that would hold your Array like `$spc = json_decode($_POST['specific']); foreach($spc as $i => $v){/*loop here*/};`. In the comment above `data:tableToJson('#tableId')` would not work because there is no Object property for PHP to refer to, unless you change `tableToJson` to return an Object that has a property that `$_POST` or `$_GET` can add to their Super Global Arrays. Of course, you should see `if(isset($_POST['specific'])){}`.

Comment: Should we talk on chat? I've only seen the link now

Answer (score 1):

```
return [
    $('td',this).map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get()
];
```

This generates this format `['x','1']`

You can change it to create a result object, and for each `td`:

- get the key from `$(this).attr('name')`
- get the value from `$(this).text()`
- extend the result object with `result[key] = value`

The solution:

```
var result = {}
$('td',this).each(function(){
    var key = $(this).attr('name');
    var value = $(this).text();
    result[key] = value;
}).get()
return result;
```